# how to check error in xml(php)?

Tags: php, xml

I have a code who more or less looks like this:

```
        do {

            if (file_exists($_FILES['file_' . $c]['tmp_name'])) {

                $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['file_' . $c]['tmp_name']);
...
```

Now yes, sometimes we are going in August with the xml file contains any error, and immediately shows me a white screen instead of for example who write the file contains an error

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the top of your php file for displaying any error messages.

Comment: but the point is to check the teeth is poprwany if and how it is nothing to do and how not a mistake. enclosure is located in the function

Answer (score 0):

If you get a white screen, you probably get a fatal error and dont have error reporting on at all:
you could try this things:
turn php_errors on
put error reporting on a higher level

If there is nothing after that and it comes trough that code. You can catch the errors using [libxml_get_errors()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php)